# Calculate Days Present and absent from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, unpivot

I have a table name `Emp_mon_day` which consists Employees **Present** and **Absent details**.

**What I want is**

I need for these 9 employees, information about days present and days absent for each employees from `Emp_mon_day`  table merged in to below query

**QUERY**

```
SELECT e.comp_mkey,
   e.status,
   e.resig_date,
   dt_of_leave,
   e.emp_name,
   e.date_of_joining,
   e.emp_card_no,
   a.pl_days,
   pl_days_opening,
   a.month1,
   a.month2,
   a.month3,
   a.month4,
   a.month5,
   a.month6,
   a.month7,
   a.month8,
   a.month9,
   a.month10,
   a.month11,
   a.month12,       
   a.month1 + a.month2 + a.month3 + a.month4 + a.month5 + a.month6 +   a.month7 + a.month8 + a.month9 + +a.month10 + a.month11 + a.month12 AS pl_sum
  FROM p_leave_allocation AS a
   INNER JOIN
   emp_mst AS e
   ON a.emp_card_no = e.emp_card_no
  WHERE  a.year = 2016
   AND (datediff(MONTH, e.date_of_joining, CONVERT (DATETIME, getdate(), 103)) >= 6
        AND datediff(MONTH, e.date_of_joining, CONVERT (DATETIME, getdate(), 103)) <= 36)
   AND (e.resig_date IS NULL
        OR (e.dt_of_leave IS NOT NULL
            AND e.dt_of_leave >= CONVERT (DATETIME, getdate(), 103)))
   AND e.status IN ('A', 'S')
   AND e.comp_mkey IN (7, 110)
   AND a.Year = 2016;
```

The above query gives me data as below

[![Image data][1]][1]

Column details for `Emp_mon_day` is below

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: What must be the output format? Do you want to repeat each of these 9 records for all days

Comment: @DhruvJoshi: Naah, see the calculation of those employees of present, absent i want to merge that in this query

Comment: In that case do you want to count number of present/absent days

Comment: @DhruvJoshi: almost yes, the above query gives me the output for 9 employees. So for that 9 employees i want to show each employees present/absent details with merging that in the above query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below query:

```
SELECT e.comp_mkey, e.status,   e.resig_date,   dt_of_leave,    e.emp_name,
   e.date_of_joining,  e.emp_card_no,   a.pl_days,    pl_days_opening,    a.month1,
   a.month2,   a.month3,   a.month4,   a.month5,   a.month6,   a.month7,   a.month8,
   a.month9,   a.month10,   a.month11,   a.month12,       
   a.month1 + a.month2 + a.month3 + a.month4 + a.month5 + a.month6 +   a.month7 + a.month8 + a.month9 + +a.month10 + a.month11 + a.month12 AS pl_sum,
   m.[DaysAbsent],m.[DaysPresent]
  FROM p_leave_allocation AS a
   INNER JOIN
   emp_mst AS e
   ON a.emp_card_no = e.emp_card_no
   INNER JOIN
   (
   SELECT 
        comp_mkey,emp_mkey,[month],[year], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN data ='AB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [DaysAbsent],
        SUM(CASE WHEN data ='P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [DaysPresent]
    FROM
        (
        SELECT comp_mkey,emp_mkey,[month],[year],[Day1],[Day2],[Day3],[Day4],[Day5]
        --,...  
        FROM Emp_mon_day
        ) source
        UNPIVOT
        (
        data FOR day IN ([Day1],[Day2],[Day3],[Day4],[Day5]) -- dynamic query can generate all days data
        )up
        GROUP BY comp_mkey, emp_mkey,[month],[year]
   ) AS m
   ON m.comp_mkey=e.Comp_mkey and m.emp_mkey=e.mkey
   --- ABOVE CRITERIA NEEDS TO BE CHECKED
  WHERE  a.year = 2016
   AND (datediff(MONTH, e.date_of_joining, CONVERT (DATETIME, getdate(), 103)) >= 6
        AND datediff(MONTH, e.date_of_joining, CONVERT (DATETIME, getdate(), 103)) <= 36)
   AND (e.resig_date IS NULL
        OR (e.dt_of_leave IS NOT NULL
            AND e.dt_of_leave >= CONVERT (DATETIME, getdate(), 103)))
   AND e.status IN ('A', 'S')
   AND e.comp_mkey IN (7, 110)
   AND a.Year = 2016;
```

**Explanation:**

We've added another INNER JOIN to the existing query to get collated data of `DaysPresent` and `DaysAbsent`

To optimize this further, I'd suggest you directly apply following `WHERE` clause to `source` set

```
WHERE  comp_mkey IN (7, 110) AND Year = 2016;
```

Comment: This means that you do not have  `emp_card_no` column in `Emp_mon_day`. Please let me know the join criteria between `Emp_mon_day` and `emp_mst`

Comment: @coder I can't troubleshoot beyond this as I do not have access to schema and data. Please troubleshoot by executing the inner query to see if that produces any data. If that does, next thing would be to examine the join criteria so that data comes through correctly. Since you get 0 records now , INNER JOIN is to blame as it did not match anything between two tables.